# Getting cross thread exception in windows phone 8 using map controls

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps, polyline

I am working on a map control in windows phone 8. I have declared a MapPolyLine field variable

```
private MapPolyline _line;
```

After initializing my Main Page I add this to my Map control.

```
_line = new MapPolyline();
_line.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
_line.StrokeThickness = 5;
Map.MapElements.Add(_line);
```

On the PositionChanged event I check for this condition.

```
if (_line.Path.Count > 0)
```

and then update the Map accordingly with this line.
i.e.

```
var previousPoint = _line.Path.Last();
var distance = coord.GetDistanceTo(previousPoint);`
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude);

Map.Center = coord;
_line.Path.Add(coord);
```

But I get Unauthorized Access, cross thread exception.
So I tried to put all my code including the 'if' condition under this

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    // Update Map
});
```

Now the exception is not thrown, but when I hover my mouse over _line.Path.Count, it still throws an exception, but the only difference is that it is not thrown.

Is it because I have not yet moved or changed my location?. Dont know but any help on the same please, anyone?.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Also one more thing for this. Do I have to use GeoCoordinate Watcher to update the line, or geolocator is fine.

Comment: Ok I checked the error again and it has to do something with dependency object. This is the whole error
unauthorizedaccessexception:invalid cross-thread access. system.dependencyobject.getvalueinternal(dependencyproperty dp)

Comment: Anyone any help or have ideas??..

Comment: So you always check if there are more than 0 coordinates in the line path *before* adding a point. With that logic, you'll never add a point to the line. When do you add the first point?

Comment: As an aside, where do you plug your mouse into your phone?